# Bot can't insert into SQL database by WCF (connected service)?

Tags: c#, wcf, botframework

I Have a WCF consumed by several clients:

1. WinForms,
2. ASP MVC 5,
3. And A am trying to use a bot

The problem is even if I can access my Data Access Layer inside when using the bot, I can't insert. [image: 0 row modified] When calling with web the same method it can insert. At the beginning I thought it was a problem with 
my WCF which is in .net framework 4.6. With 
the bot being .net core 2.1.

I can't understand why my stored procedure can't insert with the bot
while getting the same parameters from  all clients. It' s only with the bot 
that it's refusing to insert

here are my ConnecedService to wcf
[image]

and this how i call the wcf inside my bot
I just getting the parameter from LUIS and give it to the service

[image]
Many Thanks for sharing skills with a newbie 
 and be indulgent with me ... 
 Dear Respected Masters -)

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what the error is?

Comment: Include your code snippet, screenshot is not enough to resolve your issue.

Comment: there is no exception it isn't  just inserting but the SP exists and have the right type and name of parameters ,when trying to insert i can see no  row inserted i must throw my own business because otherwise i won't even notice

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the way it captures the title of the book that  i want to insert:

it seems like when i write "c# in depth" he transforms it in "c # in depth"
because i am just using a simple entitie with  LUIS without structure so  the title must be inserted exactly as the one in my db ;

it isn't as in web side  where you just click on button capturing this particular book without writing yourself the title... 
the code isn't the solution it just to make your understand the point..

var cInDepth = titre.ToLower().Contains("c # in depth") ? titre="c# in depth" : titre;